# Asynchronous Java RMI?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a framework or an implementation of Asynchronous Java RMI (preferably using Lipe RMI, but not absolutely necessary). I have done a little googling but haven't actually found a straightforward implementation yet. If any of you have already implemented it and would like to save me the time of doing it myself that would be wicked awesome.

It probably isn't relevant, but i'm going to actually be using this over Android to communicate with my RMI back end (which is why I need asynchronous RMI).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got done implementing and releasing a fork of Lipe RMI that does exactly this, in case anybody is interested.

https://github.com/terraframe/lipermi